# images on WordPress site are not showing up and I'm getting 404 errors for pictures only in wp-content/uploads/ folder

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, nginx

I'm unable to access images in wordpress. Steps taken:

## set file permissions and ownership

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 394446 Dec 25 09:10 pony.jpg
in this directory:
/srv/rufus/david_public_html/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/pony.jpg
```

## ensure nginx is serving correctly

full ningx site conf is [here](https://gist.github.com/tbbooher/5c8d12fd8ba3409cdce59e3fd96ee5f4)

```
        location / {
           try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }
```

Actual access error log:

```
 "GET /wp-content/uploads/2022/12/pony.jpg HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

## Any troubleshooting ideas?

My suspicion was that something is wrong with the nginx try_files directive, but I can serve images outside of the uploads directory.

For example, I tried:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /wp-content/uploads/$uri /index.php?$args;
```

hoping this would try the requested URI, then the requested URI with a / appended, then the image file in the /wp-content/uploads directory, and finally the /index.php file with the $args variable appended.

However, I'm still unable to view images and asking for new ideas.

One strange thing is that I can see images loaded by the theme. For example:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 103639 Dec 24 23:06 david_public_html/wp-content/themes/twentytwentytwo/assets/images/flight-path-on-transparent-d.png
```

shows up at `https://david.theboohers.org/wp-content/themes/twentytwentytwo/assets/images/flight-path-on-transparent-d.png` so this may apply only to images in the uploads folder.

more specifically:

```
  37.134.110.4 - - [25/Dec/2022:15:53:40 +0000] "GET //wp-content/themes/twentytwentytwo/assets/images/flight-path-on-transparent-d.png HTTP/2.0" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
37.134.110.4 - - [25/Dec/2022:15:53:48 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php HTTP/2.0" 200 47 "https://david.theboohers.org/wp-admin/upload.php?item=5" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
37.134.110.4 - - [25/Dec/2022:15:54:03 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2022/12/pony.jpg HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Thanks for any tips and Merry Christmas.

Comment: Check to see if you have any other Nginx directives that may be overriding this. For instance, it is common to have a `location` block for static assets that sets certain cache headers. If this is the case, remember that these blocks don’t stack/inherit from other ones, the first match wins and processing then stops

Comment: thanks. this should be the only conf file, but i'll look upstream to see what may be there.

Comment: I updated: https://gist.github.com/tbbooher/5c8d12fd8ba3409cdce59e3fd96ee5f4 I don't see anything upstream that could be causing this.

Comment: Check those `include` directives, too. Otherwise, this is when I just start commenting everything out except a single directive and work my way back

Comment: strange -- i put a file test.html in that uploads directory and I'm redirected to a php page: https://david.theboohers.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/test.html/ that produces the root of the website.

Comment: same thing with foo: https://david.theboohers.org/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/foo/ produces index.php but test.html really exists

Comment: strange. i moved the file "pony.jpg" to the themes folder and got a 404 from it. it's not nginx related.

Comment: so basically even if I upload with scp, I can't view any images. the only images that show are those that come in via a theme. it's like they were "pre-approved"

Comment: Can you tell if it is Nginx’s 404 specifically, versus PHP/WordPress?

Comment: well, i'm seeing the 404 in the nginx logs. could there be something in the wp logs?

Comment: Nginx will record the HTTP status code regardless of it generating it or WordPress. But if you look at the actual page you should hopefully be able to determine who is setting it.

Comment: Ok. It’s Nginx. But some images show in Wordpress. Not a connected to image permissions.

Comment: any ideas what I can do to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but I don't really understand it.

I had a working wordpress site, so I did a diff and saw that I had this in the wp-config.php:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '256M');
```

I know the WP_MEMORY_LIMIT setting in WordPress allows me to increase the maximum amount of memory that WordPress can use for different operations. This can be useful if you are experiencing issues with WordPress not being able to complete certain tasks due to insufficient memory, or if you are running a large WordPress site with many plugins and features that require a lot of memory to run properly.

But why would the existing images imported by the theme be visible but all other images wouldn't display? Anyway, this solved my problem.

Comment: even after this. small images are fine, but larger ones are not.

Comment: It’s not the size. It’s something about the image: header, encoding or something. Everything from photoshop doesn’t work